# Alinhar texto horizontalmente em relação a uma div na diagonal

Tags: html, css3

[image: Um código css que faça isso que está na imagem]

Olá pessoal preciso de uma ajuda pra deixar o texto alinhado a uma div torta sem distorcer o texto. (Igual na imagem) Preciso de algo em css ou css3 se possível.

Comment: Mete aqui o código que já tens

Comment: Só separei a imagem em dois col-md-6 do bootstrap e usei h1 e p sem mais formatações de alinhamento

Answer (score 0):

Vê se ajuda.

```css
#trap {
    position:absolute;
    z-index -1;
    float:left;
    margin-left:40px;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 100px solid red;
 border-right: 40px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="trap"></div>
<div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:84px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:77px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:70px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:63px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:56px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:49px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:42px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:35px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:28px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:21px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:14px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:7px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:0px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:0px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:0px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:0px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:0px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:0px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:0px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:0px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:0px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:0px"></div>
<p>
jhfjkshdfkjdshfkjhsjfhk<br/>
jksdfjkdsjf<br/>
çsjdfçlsjdf<br/>
çklsjdfçjs<br/>
çlsjdfçlj</p>
```

Dá uma olhada :[nesse](http://www.csstextwrap.com/) e [nesse](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)